# Adding field to form only if the model field is blank

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to have a form that populates fields to edit only if they are left blank. For example:

```
class UserEditConcert(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Concert
        fields = (
            'genres',
        )
        if not model.time:
            fields += ('time',)
        if model.age == "Unknown":
            fields += ('age',)
```

Neither of my if statements are working. Is my syntax wrong or is this not working for some other reason?

Comment: Well they are working, but `model.type` is the model field, not an instance field.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible to check the instance within the form class or do I need to do that in the view somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the `if` statements *are* in fact executed. But your `model.time`, obtains the field on your model. So `Concert.time`. `Concert.time` in fact returns an instance that describes the column (so probable a `models.DateTimeField`). That `DateTimeField` has truthiness `True`, hence the body of the first `if` clause does not fire. An almost equivalent procedure happens in the second case. `Concert.age` returns some field, and that field is not equal to the string `"Unknown"`.

Now we can solve the problem however by dynamically adding or removing fields in the `__init__` function. I think it is probably better to *remove* fields. Since then we do not have to add a lot of procedural logic to specify the field, widget, etc.

We can write it like:

```
class UserEditConcert(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        super(UserEditConcert, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.time:
            del self.fields['time']
        if self.instance.age != "Unknown":
            del self.fields['age']

    class Meta:
        model = models.Concert
        fields = ('genres', 'time', 'age')
```

We add some tests to specify when to remove certain fields from the form.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Unfortunately, I'm still getting a NameError, indicating that instance is not defined. It's being passed from my view, so I'm not sure why. *args should handle it, right?

Comment: @Danny: sorry, forgot the `self.` for the instance.

Comment: you, sir, are a badass. I greatly appreciate your help with this.